# Is it possible to put a PCIe 2.0 graphics card on a motherboard with PCI-Express?

Tags: motherboard, pci-express

my motherboard (MSI-7360) says it supports PCI-EXPRESS but does it also support PCIe2.0 cards?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is not really about the board, but rather the card. Virtually all PCIe 2.0 cards are backward compatible with PCIe 1.1. (they are supposed to be at least).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express#PCI_Express_2.0 (go down about half way to "PCI Express 2.0")

Comment: Post what card you want to add for a more definitive answer.

Comment: thanks! i dont know yet, which card to get. i wanted to make sure i am looking for the right thing first.

Comment: ok i will probably get a Sapphire Radeon HD 6950